# Why can't App Engine find CSS in local dev?

Tags: css, google-app-engine

I'm playing with GAE on osX and I can't seem to figure out how to link the Jquery stylesheets to the page.
The css worked fine when I linked to the CDN, but I wanted to modify the CSS.

I put the local css file in style/   and made sure the handler was setup with path to the CSS.

```
<link html="style/jquery.mobile.custom.structure.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type='text/css'>
```

Here is the app.yaml:

```
application: workoutlog  
version: 1  
runtime: python27  
api_version: 1  
threadsafe: yes  

handlers:  

- url: /style  
  static_dir: style  

- url: /favicon\.ico    
  static_files: favicon.ico  
  upload: favicon\.ico    

- url: .*  
  script: workoutlog.application  

libraries:  
- name: webapp2  
  version: latest  
- name: jinja2  
  version: latest
```

Here is the header of the HTML file:

```
<head>  
<!-- Include meta tag to ensure proper rendering and touch zooming -->  
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">  

<!-- THIS CSS IS NOT SHOWING UP? -->  
<link html="style/jquery.mobile.custom.structure.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type='text/css'>  

<!-- Include the jQuery library -->  
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>  

<!-- Include the jQuery Mobile library -->  
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>  
</head>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Change:   

 <link html="style/jquery.mobile.custom.structure.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type='text/css'>

 to:

 <link href="style/jquery.mobile.custom.structure.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type='text/css'>
```

Comment: Documentation: [`<link>` @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link#attr-href)